# C# generics and interfaces and simple OO

Tags: c#, oop, generics

My C# skills are low, but I can't understand why the following fails:

```
public interface IQuotable {}
public class Order : IQuotable {}
public class Proxy {
  public void GetQuotes(IList<IQuotable> list) { ... }
}
```

Then the code is as follows:

```
List<Order> orders = new List<Orders>();
orders.Add(new Order());
orders.Add(new Order());

Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
proxy.GetQuotes(orders); // produces compile error
```

Am I simply doing something wrong and not seeing it? Since Order implements Quotable, a list of order would go in as IList of quoatables. I have something like in Java and it works, so I'm pretty sure its my lack of C# knowledge.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't convert from a `List<Order>` to an `IList<IQuotable>`. They're just not compatible. After all, you can add *any* kind of `IQuotable` to an `IList<IQuotable>` - but you can only add an `Order` (or subtype) to a `List<Order>`.

Three options:

- If you're using .NET 4 or higher, you can use covariance if you change your proxy method to:

  ```
  public void GetQuotes(IEnumerable<IQuotable> list)
  ```

  This only work if you only need to iterate over the list, of course.
- You could make `GetQuotes` generic with a constraint:

  ```
  public void GetQuotes<T>(IList<T> list) where T : IQuotable
  ```
- You could build a `List<IQuotable>` to start with:

  ```
  List<IQuotable> orders = new List<IQuotable>();
  orders.Add(new Order());
  orders.Add(new Order());
  ```

Comment: Thank you! My thinking always was List is concrete implementation of IList. Order is the same (but there could be more IQuotables of course. So I can pass anything into method as long as they implement IList with IQuotable. Obviously that is not the case so I have to read up on covariance. I'm using .net 2 because this is a CLR stored procedure which take .net 2 only. In the end, I've used your 2nd example which, I think, makes sense and does what exactly what I need.

Answer (score 9):

`IList` is not covariant. You can't cast a `List<Order>` to an `IList<Quotable>`.

You can change the signature of `GetQuotes` to:

```
public void GetQuotes(IEnumerable<IQuotable> quotes)
```

Then, materialize a list (if you need its features), through:

```
var list = quotes.ToList();
```